# Vis.js: Stay in addEdgeMode / Event after edge adding

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I would like to stay in `addEdgeMode` in *vis.js* after adding an edge. Is there a way to achieve this?

My idea was to enable `addEdgeMode` again after adding an edge.
Is there an event that is triggered **after** adding an edge?
I know that there is the `addEdge` option in manipulation. However, this is triggered **before** the insertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can enable the addEdge again right after the previous adding, 
like this:

```
manipulation: {
          enabled: false,
          addNode: function (data, callback) {
              // filling in the popup DOM elements
              console.log('add', data);
          },
          editNode: function (data, callback) {
              // filling in the popup DOM elements
              console.log('edit', data);
          },
          addEdge: function (data, callback) {
              console.log('add edge', data);
              if (data.from == data.to) {
                  var r = confirm("Do you want to connect the node to itself?");
                  if (r === true) {
                      callback(data);
                  }
              }
              else {
                  callback(data);
              }
              // after each adding you will be back to addEdge mode
              network.addEdgeMode();
          }
```

see the last row in this code example.

```
network.addEdgeMode();
```

this will enable the addEdge mode right after the callback fired.

see this example in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bYweWazPIPgG8smhrNAw?p=preview)